# I can this specific error while download nltk

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, nltk

```py
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
```

showing error:

```
[nltk_data] Error loading punkt: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] A
[nltk_data]     connection attempt failed because the connected party
[nltk_data]     did not properly respond after a period of time, or
[nltk_data]     established connection failed because connected host
[nltk_data]     has failed to respond>
```

I have pip installed `nltk` and tried downloading the full `nltk` version for my learning.

```py
# I used this key to download full version
import nltk
nltk.download()
```

showing the error: WinError 10060

Comment: There is a network error; we can't troubleshoot that from the information you provided.

Comment: Seems like a network connection problem. There isn’t enough information here to help diagnose it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the network to another wifi connection worked for me. The previous connection had some sort of blockers for me. Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You could also try using a VPN and switching to another location.