# Error loading stopwords: <urlopen error [WinError 10060]?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

For a sentiment analysis project, I needed to use 'nltk'.

```
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
```

but while running this, I keep getting this error,

```
[nltk_data] Error loading stopwords: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] A 
[nltk_data]     connection attempt failed because the connected party  
[nltk_data]     did not properly respond after a period of time, or
[nltk_data]     established connection failed because connected host 
[nltk_data]     has failed to respond>
```

I have searched everywhere, but haven't got any solutions.
I have used this in Spyder and Jupiter notebook, but both show the same problem.
I am using mobile hotspot, is that why I am getting this error?
I have tried using this code in Google Collab, in there it works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can this specific error while download nltk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74921920/i-can-this-specific-error-while-download-nltk)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a known error for some networks.

https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1981#issuecomment-1804689730

> It seems to be that on some networks, I've been told "Jio" is one of them, raw.githubusercontent.com is not accessible, e.g.: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nltk/nltk_data/gh-pages/packages/tokenizers/punkt.xml